# Ubuntu 14.04 Xorg.conf Problems

Tags: xorg, mouse, 14.04

Recently I updated from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and i had a Mad Catz Rat 7 working fine. I followed a tutorial on editing the xorg.conf file and mapping the buttons

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Mouse Remap"
MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.7 Mouse"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 9 10 11 12 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

In 14.04, I can't seem to get it working. I followed the same steps but this time i get a warning

```
jayden@jayden-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
[sudo] password for jayden: 

(gedit:4347): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed:  
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name  
org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(gedit:4347): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed:   
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name  
org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

I have no idea what this means but nothing is working and i can't seem to find any hints as to why...

Comment: These warnings are related to gedit and not xorg.conf

Comment: thats maybe couse there isn't a xorg.conf in the X11 im having troubles with this one cose im using it in parallels (just to try) and i can't change the resolution, there is only the 800x600 i am sad for that... hope somebody can help us...

Comment: I tried adding the xorg.conf to the X11 folder an it has made no difference?.

Comment: After a bit of tampering with things i managed to get it working (not sure what i did)
However when i start my computer and log in, i have to log out and in again for it to take affect. This is not a big deal but if anyone knows why?

Comment: I just found out there is a fix in the 3.16 kernal update if anyone else has had this trouble. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/linux-kernel-3-16-changes-drivers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these error occurs because there is no xorg.conf in the directory /etc/X11/. You have to create a file or download it from somewhere else.Then you have to edit the file like you tried before.

To make your changes work, you have to restart your xserver by using this command `sudo restart lightdm`